# Which Romance languages have three verbs for, and preserved the differences between, Latin's esse, sedere, stare?

Tags: latin, romance-languages

[Yoïn van Spijk's](https://www.linkedin.com/in/yvanspijk/?originalSubdomain=nl) [diagram](https://twitter.com/yvanspijk/status/1402532103678537729) substantiates that French, Italian, Portuguese, and Spanish merged at least two of Latin's *esse, sedere, stare*.

1. Are there any [Romance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_languages) languages which still feature direct descendants of *esse, sedere, stare* as three separate, non-merged verbs (not counting derived verbs like *adesse*)?
2. This diagram doesn't indicate a Proto-Romance equivalent to *sedere*. Was there one, or was this verb perhaps lost as a full verb of its own already by Proto-Romance times?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Most languages do, such as English: "sit", "be", "stand".

Comment: @Draconis Presumably which _Romance_ languages.

Comment: Romanian only uses the equivalent(s) of *sum-esse-fui* in the sense of *to be*.

Comment: @Draconis: Yes, but not in the sense of *to be*.

Comment: Raeto-Romance declension of [*to be*](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/go.php?&D1=56&T1=esser).

Comment: @Lucian The use of these three verbs to mean "to be" was a Romance development. In Latin, _stare_ means "stand" and _sedere_ means "sit".

Comment: @Draconis: I don't recall implying otherwise.

Comment: @Draconis I edited my question. Dr. Jacquet is right. This here refers to Romance languages.

Comment: @Coosf I’ve added a further edit to clarify and flesh things out, based on your comments here. (And I’m not a doctor or German – Janus will do.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Are there any Romance languages which still feature direct descendants of esse, sedere, stare as three separate, non-merged verbs (not counting derived verbs like adesse)?

Yes, many of them. Spanish, for example, has *ser*, *sentar*, and *estar*, while Catalan has *ésser*, *seure*, and *estar*, and Italian has *essere*, *sedere*, and *stare*.

Some of these verbs have borrowed forms from each other (e.g. Latin *esse* had no supine so descendants took the supine of either *sedēre* or *stāre*) but they're still generally considered separate paradigms, even if certain forms overlap. (Compare English "wend", as in "wend your way", which is still considered a separate verb from "go" even though "go" stole its preterite.)

> 2. This diagram doesn't indicate a Proto-Romance equivalent to sedere. Was there one, or was this verb perhaps lost as a full verb of its own already by Proto-Romance times?

There were two, **sedēre* and **sedentāre*. The former is the one whose forms were often co-opted to fill in other paradigms; the latter comes from the Classical participle *sedent-* "sitting" and sometimes survived when sound changes made **sedēre* unusable. Both show various descendants meaning "sit": Catalan *seure* < **sedēre*, Spanish *sentar* < **sedentāre*.

(I'm not sure if you count **sedentāre* as a "derived verb"; I would group it in with forms like **essere* rather than forms like *adesse*, since it's the result of analogy in Vulgar Latin rather than a standard derivational process in Classical Latin.)

Comment: _Ser_ is specifically one of the merged verbs – it mixes forms of _sedēre_ and _esse_: the present indicative, imperfect and preterite from _esse_, the present subjunctive, infinitive (and hence future and conditional) and participles from _sedēre_. I would count _sentāre_ as a derived verb, since it’s formed as a regular frequentative, a highly productive formation type in late Latin. The only morphologically ‘unadulterated’, directly inherited verb I can think of in this group is _estar_ in Spanish and Portuguese (though this doesn’t mean ‘stand’ anymore).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Wouldn't the Classical frequentative be *_sessāre_ (cf _dictāre_ etc)?

Comment: Oh yes, of course it would! The present participle somehow became the passive participle in my mind for a second there. I’d still consider _*se(de)ntāre_ derived, but you’re right that it’s not a regular frequentative, just a (one-off?) new verb formed with the old present participle as its basis.